# windows XP can't terminate javaw.exe on shutdown

Tags: java, shutdown, windows-xp-sp3, kiosk-mode

I configured a computer with windows xp to work as a kiosk, at start-up the system runs my java application at full screen. The computer has not a keyboard neither a mouse. To shutdown the system the user have to push the power button. On shutdown the application disappear but windows show the "End program - javaw.exe" dialog with two buttons, "End now" and "Cancel". So the user have to interact with any input device to proceed.

How can I avoid this behavior?

Just to be clear, below the dialog that appears on power click, when the progress bar is complete the second one is shown. (I can't get a nice screen capture because windows doesn't let me open programs to paste the image from the clipboard after the power click)

[image]

[image]

Comment: what does javaw.exe do?  Is some file being written to or open?

Comment: I would use another operating system.  Win XP was better than Windows 95, but had many issues which were fixed in newer operating systems.

Comment: does this java application contain any services that work with infinite loops? maybe these are not terminated cleanly when you try to stop the application

Comment: The application is a Swing application that just read codes from card reader and show them on a JList

Comment: @PeterLawrey I have to use Windows XP due to licences constraints.

Comment: Win XP is 12 years old this year.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Windows XP is a requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved using java.exe instead of javaw.exe to launch my java program.